# Is there another nice Cocoa documentation viewer like "Ingredients" that is not dead?

Tags: cocoa, documentation

I refer to this project: http://fileability.net/ingredients/

The idea is wonderful and Ingredients would be perfect... except that its development seems to have halted. It's open source and on Github, but its Github page (https://github.com/fileability/Ingredients) shows that the latest contributions were made quite a while ago. It appears that, for whatever reason, interest in Ingredients has diminished and the project is dying. Which is a shame!

Do you know of any similar project?

Currently I use a custom search in Alfred that opens up a new tab in Safari with Apple's web-based version of the docs. I find them easier to navigate than the built in docs in Xcode. While this works, I can't help but think that there must be an even nicer way to use the docs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Dash](http://kapeli.com/dash/) might do what you're looking for, but it isn't free.

Comment: Trying it out now. Looks great! Thanks.

Comment: I'm Dash's developer. let me know if you need any help, or have any feedback.

Comment: Ok. Had a few hours to play with Dash. I like it. It's a pretty nice improvement, no doubt. One thing I miss dearly, however, and that Apple's web-based documentation does provide: the "Tasks" section. It does a great job summarizing what methods are used under which circumstances. I see no way to accessing this efficiently in Dash. The tasks section is there, of course, when you scroll up the current doc... but there's no shortcut to that section from anywhere within the app.

Comment: Actually that's one of Dash's features. Check the screenshot at http://kapeli.com/dashTasks.png. Oh and that table of contents also shows constants, notifications and typedefs.

Comment: Ok I'm an idiot. Sorry about that last comment. I realized that the headers of the section in the bottom left in Dash ARE the Tasks titles that I meant. Dash works great so far!